# C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': cannot load such file -- watir (LoadError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm new to Ruby and I have very little practice. I'm having difficulty compiling the instabot that is demonstrated in the following video:
[Build an Instagram autofollow bot](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cswubkLlocI&t=38s%22Build%20an%20Instagram%20Autofollow%22)

The error that appears is:

```
C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': cannot load such file -- watir (LoadError)
        from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
        from auto_follow.rb:1:in `<main>'
```

My code is like this:

```
require 'watir '
require_relative 'credentials'

username = $username
password = $password

user = 'justinbieber'

#abrir o browser e navegar até a página de login

browser = Watir::Browser.new :chrome
browser.goto = "https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/"

#navegando para os campos de login e senha e injetando informações
puts "Login in..."
browser.text_field(:name => "username").set "#{username}"
browser.text_field(:name => "password").set "#{password}"


#clicando no botao
browser.button(:class => '_ah57t _84y62 _i46jh _rmr7s').click

sleep(360)
```

Comment: You have a typo.  You want `require 'watir'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install the "watir" gem before you can `require` it in your code:

```
gem install watir
```

If you listen very carefully, [around 1:00](https://youtu.be/cswubkLlocI?t=60) the youtube video tells you this, but unhelpfully doesn't actually show it on screen :)

Comment: FWIW: You've misspelled `watir`.

Comment: I gave the command that you wrote in the folder where the application was. After a while, the watir was installed but the same error still remains @Tom Lord

Comment: C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': cannot load such file -- watir  (LoadError)
        from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
        from autofollow.rb:2:in `<main>'

Comment: C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.4.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/service.rb:59:in `binary_path':  Unable to find chromedriver. Please download the server from http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html and place it somewhere on your PATH. More info at https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver. (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::WebDriverError)

Comment: from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.4.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/service.rb:49:in `initialize'
        from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.4.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/chrome/bridge.rb:47:in `new'
        from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.4.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/chrome/bridge.rb:47:in `initialize'
        from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-

Comment: 3.4.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/driver.rb:61:in `new'
        from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.4.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/driver.rb:61:in `for'
        from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.4.0/lib/selenium/webdriver.rb:88:in `for'
        from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/watir-6.2.1/lib/watir/browser.rb:46:in `initialize'
        from auto_follow.rb:16:in `new'
        from auto_follow.rb:16:in `<main>'

Comment: ...So why don't you follow the instructions in the error message? It's pretty obvious what it's telling you to do.